# Add DIV to popup window with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So I have an HTML document containing CSS that defines the layout of a page of DIVs. I want to open a new window and add DIVs to this window containing info from an array. document.write will not work because it erases the existing page and thus removes the CSS. I have tried newwindow.document.body.appendChild() but nothing ever shows up. What am I missing?

EDIT: Okay, as it turns out my code works as intended in IE but not Chrome where I was testing it. This seems like a security measure shutting this down to me.

```
var printWindow = window.open("widgets/eSearchPlus/this_is_a_test.html", "PrintLabels", "toolbar=yes, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=780, height=200, top="+(screen.height-400)+", left="+(screen.width-840));
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = "label";
    div.innerHTML = "test";
    printWindow.document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Comment: Do a search for window.open. This is a duplicate question and will probably be closed.

Comment: I have read those questions, none of them ever get this working.

Comment: post a jsfiddle of your working code and we can fix.

Comment: I'm assuming "appentChild" is just a typo on your posted code, not your *actual* code... :)

Comment: you have a typo.  ````appendChild(div);````

Comment: haha yeah the typo was from me failing while posting it here. its not in the code.

Comment: Is the oppened window's page's url on the same domain as the parente window?

Comment: the URL is that of the local machine for both.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var printWindow = window.open("widgets/eSearchPlus/this_is_a_test.html", "PrintLabels", "toolbar=yes, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=780, height=200, top="+(screen.height-400)+", left="+(screen.width-840));

printWindow.document.body.innerHTML += '<div class="label">test</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be that you are creating an element in the parent window and trying to add it to the child window.

Try changing the element to be created in the child window document:

```
var div = printWindow.document.createElement('div');
```

Comment: I tried this just now but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Just to be sure: Is the oppened window's page's url on the same domain as the parente window?